# evaluating Pi with imaginairy unit i leads to contradiction!

Tags: complex-numbers, pi

I was reading about evaluating $i^i$ so I tried that with Mathematica and got a real (R) result and Mathematica suggested an alternative form being $e^{-pi/2}$ so I solved for $\pi$:

$i^i = e^{-\pi/2}$

$i \cdot \ln(i) = -\pi/2$

$-2i\cdot\ln(i) = \pi$

from there:

$\cos\left(-2i \cdot\ln(i)\right) = -1  \iff \cos\left(2i\cdot\ln(i)\right) = -1$

$\cos\left(2i \cdot\ln(i)\right) = -1$

$2i\cdot\ln(i) = \arccos(-1) = \pi$

so we get: $\pi = -2i \cdot \ln(i) = 2i \cdot \ln(i)$

so what did go wrong?

Comment: In the first step, you should note that $i^i$ takes infinitely many values. Also, two numbers can have the same $\cos$ value but not be the same. I.e. $\cos(0)=\cos(2\pi)$ but $0\neq2\pi$, if you see what I mean.

Comment: Likewise log z and arccos z are infinitely-many-valued functions. By the way, I believe it's customary to reserve the ln notation for the real logarithm of a positive real number; i.e., I'd write log i rather than ln i, or Log i if I wanted the principal value.

Comment: So I understand that the conclusion is wrong because the periodicity of cos(x). But what do you mean that log(z) and arccos(z) are infinitely-many-valued functions?

Comment: $i=e^{i\pi/2} =e^{-3i\pi/2}$ and many others, which means that $\ln i$ is just as much $i\pi/2$ as it is $-3i\pi/2$ or $5i\pi/2$. The inverse trigonometric functions are multivalued even for real numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done is the wrong you've done (only it's slightly hidden away):
$$
x=y\\
\cos (x)= \cos( y)\\
\cos (-x)= \cos (y)\\
-x=y
$$
In essence, just because two cosines are equal, doesn't mean the arguments are.